# Song in Mobius Dick

Tags: futurama

In Futurama episode "Mobius Dick," what is the song after Leela says "This time it's business"? I can't find this answer anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

OK. This answer's from the wackier end of futurama fan-theories so please bear with me.

Several fans have suggested that the ship pictured below, in the 'spaceship graveyard' scene is in fact based on the album cover of the 1972 album "Space Shanty", performed by the band Khan.

[image: Spaceship Graveyard]

As you can hear from the album, there are elements that certainly sound remarkably similar to the tune played in Futurama as they adapt the ship for solar sailing.